# Servlet passing empty array to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I have created a web application that uses a login page, a servlet, a managed bean, and a jsp page. No matter what I have tried I cannot get the JSP page to display an array of item names from my servlet that are acquired using an arraylist of bean objects. I even tried just creating a single bean object in the servlet and then passing just a string variable. I have tried using both session and request and cannot get this to work here is my code:

Servlet:

```
package xxxx;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class ItemServlet extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
 ItemInventory iI = new ItemInventory();
 String[] itemNames = iI.getNames();
 HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 session.setAttribute("itemNames", itemNames);
 request.setAttribute("itemNames", itemNames);
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/secureApps/ItemsCatalog.jsp");


 rd.forward(request, response);



}



@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@page import="xxxx.ItemInventory"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%

String[] itemName = (String[])session.getAttribute("itemNames");

%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Item Catalog</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Item Catalog</h1>
    <Select Name="itemNames">
        <% for(int i=0;i < itemName.length; i++){
         %>
         <option value ="<%= itemName[i]%>"><%= itemName[i]%></option>

         <%
         }
        %>

    </select> 
         ${itemBean.itemID}
</body>
</html>
```

The Bean

```
package xxxx;


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ItemBean {

String itemName;
String itemID;
String itemDescription;
String itemPrice;
String itemQuantity;


public ItemBean(){}

public ItemBean(String iD, String name, String description, String price, String quantity){

    this.itemID = iD;
    this.itemName = name;
    this.itemDescription = description;
    this.itemPrice = price;
    this.itemQuantity = quantity;


}
public String getItemName(){
    return itemName;
}


}
```

ItemInventory Class:

```
package xxxx;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ItemInventory {

ArrayList <ItemBean> items = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();

public static void main(String[] args){}


public void ItemInventory() throws IOException{

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/catalog.txt")); 
  String text = null;





      while ((text=br.readLine())!=null){
          String[] itemArray = text.split(",");
          items.add(new ItemBean (itemArray[0], itemArray[1], itemArray[2], itemArray[3], itemArray[4]));





  }

   br.close();

} 

public Integer getSize(){
    Integer x = items.size();
    return x;
}

public String[] getNames(){
    int y = items.size();
    String[] itemNames = new String[y];
    for (int i = items.size() - 1; i >=0; i--){

        itemNames[i] = items.get(i).getItemName();
    }
    return itemNames;
}

}
```

Please help, I have been at this for hours....

Comment: Did you checked size of `itemNames.length` in Servlet ?

Comment: Just did and it is coming backs as 0.....now I am even more confused

Comment: Yeah. `ItemInventory iI = new ItemInventory();` What is happening there ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that class....it is there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Servlet / JSP code.

Here, `int y = items.size();` This will always return `0` as you have initialized it earlier.

You are misunderstanding the some concepts here. When you create an object of the Class `main()` will not be executed directly. So, Here in your case it returns empty Array.

You should remove the code from `main()` and may be write a separate method to do that. Also, Its bad practice to have business logic inside constructor

Example: ItemInventory.java

```
public void fillItems(){
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/catalog.txt")); 
        String text = null;
        while ((text=br.readLine())!=null){
           String[] itemArray = text.split(","); 
           // you might want to check array size
           items.add(new ItemBean (itemArray[0], itemArray[1], itemArray[2], itemArray[3], itemArray[4]));

        }

        br.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In Servlet

```
ItemInventory iI = new ItemInventory();
iI.fillItems();
String[] itemNames = iI.getNames();
```

Comment: It works, sort of. Now I have to figure out the path my file when using netbeans...

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide code of `ItemInventory` so hard to confirm if `iI.getNames()` really return an array having data.

The code looks correct to me so it should work if `iI.getNames()` return data.

Check the length of the array.

Also I see that you are expecting a `itemBean` but not provided in the session or request scope.

Also the `itemBean` is not used on the servlet either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have also tried creating just a new ItemBean in the ItemInventory class with 5 strings being passed and getNames returning just a string, but it does not work.

Comment: Did you debug your code of reading the file? Does the file have content and does it really fill the items ArrayList?